# I don't understand Cocos 2D sprite creation behaviour in a loop

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

with this code monsters don't appear, only hero shows

```
for (int j = 0; j <= _discrH; j++)
   {
   for (int i = 0; i <= _discrW; i++)
        {
        CCSprite * sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"monster.png"] ;
        sprite.position  = ccp([self getCanvasXFromGameI : i],[self getCanvasYFromGameJ : j]);
        [_sprites addObject:sprite ];
         [self addChild:sprite];
        }
   } 
   _hero = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"case1.png"];
   _hero.position  = ccp(0,0);
   [self addChild:_hero];
```

But with this (non-sense) code, the monsters and the hero show, and I don't understand why...

```
for (int j = 0; j <= _discrH; j++)
   {
   for (int i = 0; i <= _discrW; i++)
        {
        CCSprite * sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"monster.png"] ;
        sprite.position  = ccp([self getCanvasXFromGameI : i],[self getCanvasYFromGameJ : j]);
        [_sprites addObject:sprite ];
         [self addChild:sprite];
        }
   _hero = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"case1.png"];
   _hero.position  = ccp(0,0);
   [self addChild:_hero];
   }
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: are you using ARC in your project?

Comment: From the code you posted it should work with the first snippet. You should check your loops, try doing a CCLog to see if they are actually getting executed.

Comment: Thanks for this advice. The loops are executed. The only difference between the two snippets is the "hero" sprite. If the hero sprite is outside the loops : I've got no monsters sprites at screen. If it's inside, monsters show. It's weird.

Comment: In the second snippet you are adding you hero _discrH times to the scene ... the only other problem could be with the `getCanvasXFromGameI` any y position getting methods. Try to print out these positions and see if they make sense. You could also just place them at point `CGPointZero` and see if they are added to the left corner of the screen or the middle. I really see no other possibility here from the code you posted.